# terminal and vim popped out error message

Tags: command-line, permissions, vim

In my terminal, I got repeated messages:

```
[9415:9415:0920/093654.751013:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] [.RendererMainThread-0x17a0942c3a00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete.
```

When I edit a file with vim, the error messages look like

```
[9374:9449:0920/093015.972803:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(195)] Could not create NETLINK socket: Permission denied (13)
```

any guess what went wrong?